# Which one is correct? And why

Tags: grammaticality

which one is correct ?

***Why yo don't called me***

or

***why you didn't call me?***

or

***Why you didn't called me?***

Comment: Neither one is correct. Both are ungrammatical. That's not the way questions are formed.

Comment: Then teach me..

Comment: That's a different group. See [English Language Learners.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why didn't you call me? - Something happened and you did not call

Why haven't you called me? Same as above

Why don't you call me (anymore)? - Over a period of time you did not call

Why won't you call me (anymore)? - Same as above

Hope that helps,

Regards

Comment: We cannot use 2nd form with `did`?

Comment: Ashish, yes, "did" and verb in past tense do not go together

Comment: should we always use third form with `had` and `have` ??